# WARN Test results in Robot Framework

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I have multiple test cases that need to be tested. With every release, I get some new test cases as well as some old ones.

My problem is for old test cases which are failed I have already created a problem ticket in JIRA and in the next release this ticket number is added in [Documentation] Field of the .robot

Now what I want is next time on a new release if the bug is already raised in Jira meaning the documentation section of the robot will contain the ticket number, If the test fails I will label it as WARN in Yellow instead of marking it as Failure.

I have searched a lot and found this thread but according to it I can't do it- [Github Issue](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/964) is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to process the Documentation of the test to see if it has a JIRA issue number, if so, then add a Tag (for example TagName) to it. When launching tests with robotframework version 4.0, you call them by passing the option `--skiponfailure TagName`. You will have those tests marked as SKIPPED.

The parsing of Documentation would be needed to parse before running the actual tests (in a helper test run).